# How to update a different database table with info from my current database table, using mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax

I'm trying to write a SQL query to update a field in a different database (Hosted on the same server with phpMyAdmin). I just want it to update the most recent row as the query will be run directly after a new user is added (on that new user). My goal output is to change the username field of this user to be the same as the email field of the user in the original database. The syntax error states

> 'syntax to use near 'FROM db2.users AS "data" WHERE db1.user.email =
> ...' at line 3'

I can't see where I'm going wrong - I saw another answer where a user said that mySQL does not support the FROM keyword, however I have not been able to find anywhere else that backs that up. This is what I currently have for my code:

```
UPDATE db1.user
SET username = data.username
FROM db2.users AS "data"
WHERE db1.user.email = data.email
AND db1.user.id = (
SELECT MAX(id) 
FROM db1.user
)
LIMIT 1
```

If anyone knows where I'm going wrong with this it would be much appreciated!

Comment: SET comes later in MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, the syntax would be:

```
UPDATE db1.user u JOIN
       db2.users u2
       ON u.email = u2.email JOIN
       (SELECT MAX(u2.id) as max_id
        FROM db1.user u2
       ) uu
       ON uu.max_id = u.id
    SET u.username = u2.username;
```

Notes:

It seems odd that you are not filtering by email to get the maximum `id`, but that is how your question is stated.  Also, MySQL doesn't support `LIMIT` in multi-table `UPDATE` queries.

Comment: I've been playing around with this, however am still getting an error
 `syntax to use near '"data"
ON u.email = data.email
JOIN (SELECT MAX(u2.id) as max_id FROM ...' at line 2`

The reason I'm not filtering by email to get the maximum ID is because I'm new to SQL, I'll look into modifying it to do that instead, assuming it is better practice. I'll also play around and see if I can solve this syntax error, although let me know if there's any other pointers you have. Cheers

Comment: @Raaa . . . `"data"` seems like a really bad choice for a table alias anyway, so I just changed it to something more reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for that - I only had it set to "data" to make it a little easier to read, as I've inherited this database with a bunch of long & confusing names! 
The SQL you've suggested works perfectly, thanks for that. It appears that I need to learn/practice my joins! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

As in your SQL you are okay with using subqueries, I would suggest to try the following:

```
UPDATE
    db1.user
SET
    username = (
    SELECT
        data.email
    FROM
        db2.users AS "data"
    WHERE
        db1.user.email = data.email)
WHERE
    db1.user.id = (
    SELECT
        MAX(id)
    FROM
        db1.user)
LIMIT 1;
```